# alternative to table structure for iframe

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

In my jsp there are 4 div which contain one or more than one iframe but we are planning to collaborate all different jsps in one main jsp. and there is suggestion to use tables but i think table element can be more useful for tabular format. so do you know which would be better approach than table structure for different div instead of iframes?

Comment: i dont want to use these many iframe in one jsp nor i want to use table struature.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why can't you just use `<div>`s?

Comment: i am using divs only. Existing implementation have iframes in those 4 divs and src is jsp page.  but i am thinking to implement jsp code in table formate in those divs without implementing iframes. so this would be right approach or not? i think this will improve performance.

Comment: Improve performance?! Anyway-I don't know what you're asking. Divs are for layout; I wouldn't use tables for layout but it's largely irrelevant.